# Calabash - can't test touch events

Tags: ios, automated-tests, calabash, calabash-ios

I'm using Calabash to automate some tests with the UI but I'm having some issues.

I have a step as follows: `Then I touch the "login" button`.

When I run `cucumber`, the console throws this error:

`Could not parse response ''; the app has probably crashed (RuntimeError)`

**Environment:**

- Calabash 0.11.0
- Xcode 6.3.2
- iPhone 5 (8.3 Simulator)

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Build app to iPhone 5 8.3 simulator
- Execute: DEBUG=1 calabash-ios console
- Execute: start_test_server_in_background
- Execute: touch("button marked:'login'")

**Console trace:**

`RuntimeError: Could not parse response ''; the app has probably crashed
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/uia.rb:33:in rescue in uia'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/uia.rb:30:in uia'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/uia.rb:454:in uia_handle_command'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/uia.rb:201:in uia_tap_offset'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/actions/instruments_actions.rb:93:in query_action'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/actions/instruments_actions.rb:15:in touch'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:1166:in query_action_with_options'
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:177:in touch'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/felipepenariveros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in <main>'`

It might be related to this issue already closed in Github: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/600

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: What happens if you try it in console mode? Do tap_mark 'login' or touch "button marked:'login'"?

Comment: What calabash version?

Comment: @Lasse if I try console mode I get the same error.

Comment: @jmoody I'm using version 0.14.2

Comment: We need more information.  Please update your question with the Calabash version, the exact query or gesture you are trying to perform, and any stack trace information.  See the https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki for tips on how to ask good questions and for examples of good bug reports.

Comment: @jmoody Just edited the question with deeper info.

Comment: Perfect!  Does the app crash?  What happens if you do:  query("button marked:'login'") and query("* marked:'login'")?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78480/discussion-between-jmoody-and-felipe-pena).

Comment: @jmoody ok, I'm there. I did also tried `query("button marked:'login'")` and it works as expected (returns and logs the object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.

In the simulator, I chose *Reset Content & Settings...* and it worked.

Thanks though for helping out! (@jmoody & @Lasse).

Comment: I have the same problem but it was not solved by "Reset Content & Settings..."Any other ideas?

Comment: It was a bit too much to explain here so I made another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062753/cant-update-calabash-server-version

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my project (Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9.0.2 on a physical device (iPod touch), Calabash 0.14.3).

What worked for me was changing the `:uia_strategy` from `:shared_strategy` to `:host`.  So now my before scenario block in features/support/01_launch.rb looks like this:

```
Before do |scenario|
  options = {
    :uia_strategy => :host      #used to be shared_strategy - but that failed
  }
  @calabash_launcher = Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher.new
  unless @calabash_launcher.calabash_no_launch?
    @calabash_launcher.relaunch(options)
    @calabash_launcher.calabash_notify(self)
  end
end
```

Hopefully this helps someone else down the line who is racking their brain over a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I actually stopped using Calabash and started using UI tests inside of Xcode.