# Can't update calabash server version

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, xamarin, ios-simulator, calabash

Having a problem updating the Calabash server version.
The problem is that I can run basic tests that check for elements... However, once I try to "touch" buttons calabash returns

> RuntimeError: Could not parse response ''; the app has probably crashed

The origin of the problem, I believe, is that my server version is old/incompatible. Not rocket science:

> WARN: The server version is not compatible with gem version. Please
> update your server.
> https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B1-Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version
>
> ```
> gem version: '0.14.3' 
> min server version: '0.14.3'
> server version: '0.9.169'
> ```

The link is outdated, but I followed all steps in https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version many times.
And still when I check the version it is 0.9.169

```
irb(main):006:0> server_version['version']
"0.9.169"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it!

It turns out that it all had to do with the calabash component in my Xamarin project.

When I first started experimenting with tests few month ago I added the  calabash component (image below)

[image: Calabash component]

When I started adding some more tests now, I still had the same component. This component is up to date as far as I can tell. I then tried to remove it and add it again but I could no longer find it.

Turns out that now it is called "Xamarin Test Cloud Agent". I installed that component and DONE.

[image: Xamarin Test Cloud Agent]

Hope this helps anyone.