# Calabash-iOS error message: "The server version is not compatible with gem version"

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I keep getting this message every time I run `cucumber` for Calabash-iOS. The link in the message doesn't provide any help in resolving the issue as far as I can tell. The test still runs with pass/fail results, but I'd like to resolve this problem.

I'm running the simulator locally and not using Xamarin, so [this link's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062753/cant-update-calabash-server-version) answer doesn't help me.

Does anyone know how to update the server version?

[image]

Comment: Did you try the steps listed here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version#is-the-gem-compatible-with-the-embedded-server ?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed steps on [github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/…](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version#is-the-gem-compatible-with-the-embedded-server) and it is now resolved.